# Reading value from Web.Config that uses configSource files

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config, configurationmanager

In keeping with the [recommendation here](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/16/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx) we separated our connection string into an xml file. Our web.config:

```
//old - works
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" 
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<connectionStrings>
//new - fails
<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config" />
```

content of connections.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Both files are located in the project root folder. EntityFramework works fine with both solutions. However when I try to obtain the connection string for some tests it fails to retrieve.This is the code that we use to extract the connection string:

```
string ConnectionString =
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Reading the connection string direct from web.config works, when we introduce the ConfigSource it fails. What do we need to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Copy to Output Directory` property of your configuration file to either `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

[image]

If you don't do this, your `ConnectionStrings.config` file will not be copied to the output debug/release folder and so will not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the external file should have the same name as of the section name. Like it should be connectionStrings.config, not connections.config

Comment: That may be good practice, but it is not required. This works: connectionStrings configSource="connections.config". The configSource can contain any (config) file name.